# Logging in a console application which hosts a NancyFx web service

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, nancy

**What I am doing**
I am writing a Nancy self hosting application (runs in a console window)

**My problem**
I cannot get log4net to log anything to my console window. (Specifically - I cannot get this to work when hosting a NancyFx service, I have no problem using Log4Net in other console applications.)

**What I have researched**
I have looked at the following pages (in addition to searching StackOverflow):
http://www.philhack.com/wire-up-log4net-to-nancy/
https://lookonmyworks.co.uk/2012/03/14/logging-unhandled-exceptions-with-nancy/

**My log4net Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <configSections>
         <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
      </configSections>

      <log4net>
         <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
             <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
               <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level: %message%newline" />
            </layout>
         </appender>

         <root>
            <level value="DEBUG"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
         </root>
      </log4net>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
 </configuration>
```

**Example of my usage of Log4Net**

```
 public class MyNancyModule : NancyModule
 {
    private static ILog Logger = LogManager.LogFactory.GetLogger(typeof(MyNancyModule));

    public MyNancyModule()
    {
       Logger.Debug("This is a test");
    }
 }
```

**My problem (again)**
I cannot get log4net to log anything to my console window using the above configuration. I understand from the blog posts above that Nancy does something to configure the error handling pipelines which interferes with log4Net, but I don't quite understand what it is doing or how.

How can I get log4Net working in a self hosted Nancy service in order to log to the console window (I am not particularly interested in logging to the in-built diagnostics page)?

I haven't tried adding the log manager to the IOC container as in all my other applications, I usually have a static log manager per class which gives me class specific logging - the example in the blog post will log everything as having originated from the bootstrapper class.

**Edit**
I forgot to mention that I am using ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net for the logManager. It also doesn't appear to work in my example if I do:

```
private static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ApiReverseProxyModule));
```

Comment: Where / when do you load the log4net configuration?

Comment: @stuartd Your question was pertinent - I forgot to add the line `LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(configureLog4Net: true);` to my main method. If you want the rep, add this as the answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Seems a bit thin for an answer but thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stuartd for pointing me in the right direction. The blogs I mentioned were a bit misleading - turns out I was missing

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(configureLog4Net: true);
```

from my main method - so I was always using a null logging factory.

This appears to be nothing to do with NancyFX!

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

i use log4net like:

First you must define once the XmlConfigurator:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile));
```

and the you can use it in the Classes:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger("ClassName");

log.Debug("What you want...");
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this using NancyFx? I've just tried adding the code you suggested into my Main file, and it hasn't made any difference. It works fine for a standard console application (as does the configuration I posted above), but not when self hosting a NancyFx service.

Comment: OK, for ASP.NET Application it works different, you must use a different Appender. The TraceAppender is your choice: http://interactivelogic.net/wp/2010/02/aspnet-logging-to-output-window-with-log4net/